# How to change xLable format (i want to get month in word) using morris.js in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, morris.js

Screen shot for my Request.

[image: Screen shot for my Request]

Here I want to change the xLable (2018-01 - to - Jan) and here am using `morris.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set use the function `xLabelFormat` with moment.js as follow:

```
xLabelFormat: function (x) { 
    return moment(x).format('YYYY-MMM');
}
```

More info about this function is available in the documentation:
https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html